# Java: can you cast Class into a specific interface?

Tags: java, class

I've got a project I am working on and in this project I would like to include the ability for developers to include their own plugins without having to change the whole code.

This is what I have developed for it so far.
this is the interface that the plugins are using.

```
package com.pennion.pennpad;

public interface action{
 void doAction();
}
```

This is the main code that loads the plugins among other things.

```
 Map menuMap=new HashMap();
 Map actionCommands=new HashMap();
 public void load3rdPartyMenu() throws Exception{
  String userHome=System.getProperty("user.home");
  String sep=File.getSeparator();
  String fileString=userHome+sep+"pennion"+sep+"pennpad"+sep+"plugins"+sep+"plugins.conf";
  File cfgFile=new File(fileString);
  BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileStreamReader(cfgFile)));
  String ln="";
  boolean menuFound=false;
  while((ln=in.readLine())!=null){
   if(!menuFound){
    if(ln.equals("//!==Menu!==//")){
     menuFound=true;
    } else{
     menuFound=false;
    }
   } else{
    String pluginName="";
    String pluginDescription="";
    String KeyMask="";
    String[] split=ln.split("||");
    pluginName=split[0];
    KeyMask=split[1];
    pluginDescription=split[2];
    ClassLoader pluginLoader=ClassLoader.getClassLoader();
    Class c=pluginLoader.loadClass("com.pennion.3rdparty."+pluginName);
    Map keyMap=new HashMap();
    String[] kmSplit=KeyMask.split("+");
    if(kmSplit[0].equals("CTRL")){
     keyMap.put("ActionEvent",ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK);
    } else if(kmSplit[0].equals("SHIFT")){
     keyMap.put("ActionEvent",ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK);
    } else if(kmSplit[0].equals("ALT")){
     keyMap.put("ActionEvent",ActionEvent.ALT_MASK);
    } else if(kmSplit[0].equals("ALT_CTRL")||kmSplit[0].equals("CTRL_ALT")){
     keyMap.put("ActionEvent",ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK+ActionEvent.ALT_MASK);
    } else if(kmSplit[0].equals("SHIFT_CTRL")||kmSplit[0].equals("CTRL_SHIFT")){
     keyMap.put("ActionEvent",ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK+ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK);
    } else if(kmSplit[0].equals("ALT_SHIFT")||kmSplit[0].equals("SHIFT_ALT")){
     keyMap.put("ActionEvent",ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK+ActionEvent.ALT_MASK);
    }
    keyMap.put("KeyBind",getKeyBinding(kmSplit[1]));
    this.addMenuItem("Plugin",pluginName,keyMap.get("KeyBind"),keyMap.get("ActionEvent"),keyMap.get("KeyBind"),pluginName,c);
   }
  }
 }
 public int getKeyBinding(String k){
  if(k.equals("A")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_A;
  } else if(k.equals("B")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_B;
  } else if(k.equals("C")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_C;
  } else if(k.equals("D")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_D;
  } else if(k.equals("E")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_E;
  } else if(k.equals("F")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_F;
  } else if(k.equals("G")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_G;
  } else if(k.equals("H")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_H;
  } else if(k.equals("I")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_I;
  } else if(k.equals("J")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_J;
  } else if(k.equals("K")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_K;
  } else if(k.equals("L")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_L;
  } else if(k.equals("M")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_M;
  } else if(k.equals("N")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_N;
  } else if(k.equals("O")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_O;
  } else if(k.equals("P")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_P;
  } else if(k.equals("Q")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_Q;
  } else if(k.equals("R")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_R;
  } else if(k.equals("S")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_S;
  } else if(k.equals("T")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_T;
  } else if(k.equals("U")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_U;
  } else if(k.equals("V")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_V;
  } else if(k.equals("W")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_W;
  } else if(k.equals("X")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_X;
  } else if(k.equals("Y")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_Y;
  } else if(k.equals("Z")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_Z;
  } else if(k.equals("1")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_1;
  } else if(k.equals("2")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_2;
  } else if(k.equals("3")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_3;
  } else if(k.equals("4")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_4;
  } else if(k.equals("5")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_5;
  } else if(k.equals("6")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_6;
  } else if(k.equals("7")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_7;
  } else if(k.equals("8")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_8;
  } else if(k.equals("9")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_9;
  } else if(k.equals("0")){
   return KeyEvent.VK_0;
  } else{
   return 0;
  }
 }
```

I need a way to cast the loaded class as an action because as of now it is being considered a class by the compiler and can't be added to the actionCommands hashmap.

and is there an easier way to process which KeyEvent is being asked for by the loaded String?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of comment in the code I am still working on it.. and practice bad coding habits =\

Comment: As for the second question, you may consider having a mapping between the strings and the KeyEvent constants.

Does it help if you change "Map actionCommands=new HashMap();" to "Map<String,action> actionCommands=new HashMap<String,action>();"? (Or something similar, you didn't specify how you were using the map).  IOW, try using generics to make your code more explicit in the types you're using.

Comment: whats odd is the suggestion is how my map is coded in my file when I pasted it over it didn't copy the <String, action>...

Comment: The interface name should start with a capital letter, like Action. [Name conventions in Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-141855.html#1852) are widely respected, unlike other languages.

Comment: I know, I needed to change the interface name because javax.swing.Action already exists and as such the compiler throws an error.

Comment: I used The solution I marked with change of newInstance() as suggested by the commentor but also changed some of my code based off of Erikson's suggestion. If anyone knows of a faster way of parsing out the KeyEvents and ActionEvents just let me know ;)
Though I do think as suggested by Steve Howard that a mapping of sorts might make it easier than what I have there. I'll look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't cast a Class direct to something.

You can create a object of it and then cast it to your interface.

```
Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
Action actionObj = (Action) obj;
```

Follow the conventions, class names starts with upper case.

Comment: Can't you just directly instantiate as the interface, such as `Action actionObj = clazz.createNewInstance();`

Comment: There is no `createNewInstance()` method on `Class`.

Comment: Ty.. I just write from memory. Edited. And you can't cast directly, unless you have a instance of Class<Action>.

Answer (score 3):

So far, in the code you show, you only have a `Class`, not an instance of that class.

At some point, you'll need to construct an instance from the `Class`; that instance is what you'll cast to an `Action`.

```
/* Load the plugin class. */
Class<?> clz = Class.forName("com.y.plugins.MyCustomAction");
/* Make sure the named class is the right type. */
Class<? extends Action> sub = clz.asSubclass(Action.class);
/* Get the default constructor. */
Constructor<? extends Action> ctor = sub.getConstructor();
/* Create an instance of "MyCustomAction". */
Action custom = ctor.newInstance();
```

Comment: Actually, you don't need to get the Constructor for that, for the default (no parameters), you can call the newInstance directly on the Class object.

Comment: @Marcos Vasconcelos - I prefer to use the newer API (obtaining the constructor) for consistency with dynamic method invocations. For one thing, you get better error reporting; if the constructor doesn't exist, you get an `NoSuchMethodException`, rather than than an `IllegalAccessException` (which can also mean that the constructor exists but isn't accessible).

Answer (score 0):

For your 1st question, you will have to make an instance of the loaded class and then cast it..

So,

```
cInstance = c.newInstance();
((action)cInstance).doAction();
```

For your 2nd question, I can't think of a quicker way to decode Strings into static variables.