# Creating objects in java, without knowing the Class at compile time

Tags: java, reflection

I have a Java question. I have a configuration file that I read and extract some paths to java classes, let's say to an ArrayList of strings (for convenience I will call it **path2libs**).

I want to create an instance for every one of these classes dynamically by iterating this '**path2libs**' array. I tried out something like this:

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("test.Demo"); 
Demo demo = (Demo) clazz.newInstance();
```

But I can't know what classes I will read, so I cannot do the appropriate casting.

When this is done, I want to call a method on each object (it is the same method in each case). All of these objects are based on an interface so I know their methods.

So, basically (to summarize) I have two questions :)

1. Create the desirable objects
2. Call a method on each object

Comment: You can cast to the interfaces, and call the methods through the interface reference. If you are calling a method that is declared in the interface then you don't have to cast to specific types.

Comment: If all of them depend on a common interface why don't you cast all of them to that known type? Exploit the polymorphism of the hierarchy that you have created. This is one of the scenarios where it shines.

Comment: as i mentioned below that was my first approach, but i got a "Class cannot be converted to MyInterface" error. So i though i couldn't do this. Any thoughts why i am getting this?

Comment: There is an extra step, you can cast it to an interface, but not directly. Duplicate of [Java: can you cast Class into a specific interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820507/java-can-you-cast-class-into-a-specific-interface)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues.

First, `Class#newInstance()` expects the corresponding class to have a `public` constructor with an empty parameter list. You therefore have to make sure all the classes you want to work with have that. Otherwise, you'll need to get an appropriate `Constructor`, make it accessible, and provide the appropriate arguments.

Second, do you know the interface that **all classes share** at run time? If you do, you can cast all the instances to that interface type

```
InterfaceType interfaceInstance = (InterfaceType) clazz.newInstance();
interfaceInstance.interfaceMethod(/* arguments */);
```

If you don't, you'll have to again rely on reflection.

You'll need to retrieve the `Method` for the corresponding method, providing the types of each parameter in the method's parameter list.

```
Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod("methodName" /*, possible parameter list types */);
```

You can then invoke that method on your class' instance, again providing the appropriate arguments.

```
method.invoke(interfaceInstance /*, possible arguments */);
```

Comment: And yes, it is solved. The first problem was the "public constructor with an empty parameter list" and the second is that i forgot to use the newInstance() method. Efxaristo :p

Comment: @MaRiOs Na 'sai kala. Consider upvoting any useful answers and accepting one of them that helped most.

Answer (score 2):

> "Class cannot be converted to MyInterface"

This sounds like a compiler error you'd get after trying to cast a `Class` in to a `MyInterface` like this:

```
MyInterface mi = (MyInterface)Class.forName("test.Demo");
```

This is not valid, a MyInterface is not a Class so the compiler can determine the cast can never be legal. Rather, you should cast the new instance to the MyInterface. Now, there is a way you can do this in a more type-safe way:

```
Class<?> wildCls = Class.forName("test.Demo");

Class<? extends MyInterface> miSubtypeCls = (
    wildCls.asSubclass(MyInterface.class)
);

MyInterface miSubtype = miSubtypeCls.newInstance();
```

This is similar to a non-generic version like this:

```
Class rawCls = Class.forName("test.Demo");

MyInterface miSubtype = (MyInterface)rawCls.newInstance();
```

However, the first version doesn't use raw types (which are not recommended) and instead, [`asSubclass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#asSubclass%28java.lang.Class%29) will throw the ClassCastException if `test.Demo` does not implement `MyInterface`. The method `asSubclass` is provided for this type of scenario.

Here's a short demonstration:

```
package test;

public class HelloAsSubclass
implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("hello from Runnable implementation!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Class<?> wildCls = Class.forName("test.HelloAsSubclass");

            Class<? extends Runnable> rSubtypeCls = (
                wildCls.asSubclass(Runnable.class)
            );

            Runnable r = rSubtypeCls.newInstance();
            r.run();

        } catch(
            ClassNotFoundException |
            InstantiationException |
            IllegalAccessException ex
        ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also of course make sure that your subtypes have a public no-argument constructor (or no constructor as in the above example and is essentially the same thing) which is a requirement of `newInstance`. Otherwise you would need to instantiate them [by getting a Constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mentioned above the problems that i had and your answer covers them both but i cannot set 2 accepted answers (i also cannot up-vote coz i am a newbie in stack overflow... but i am going to do it as soon as i have the required rank!)

Comment: No problem. I wanted to post the 'generically proper' way to do this. Which answer to accept is [basically up to you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/244864).

Answer (score 0):

You're doing that quite right. Only, you wouldn't cast to `Demo`, but to the common interface instead. After all, you want to do something *common* with all those instances. You want to call methods on them. Somehow you have to know that these methods are actually available. That is what interfaces are for.

Comment: that was my first approach, but i got a "Class cannot be converted to MyInterface" error. So i though i couldn't do this.

Comment: Then the class probably doesn't implement the interface. Is that the verbatim error text?